# How do I convert Class Components to Functional Components in React.js project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

In the project I watch, they work with class component, but I want to do these operations with functional component using hooks. How can you help me guys? I tried many times but couldn't do this translation. I'm still trying

My code (imported data is "ingredients"):

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      ingredients: [],
      totalPrice: 0
    }

    this.addIngredients = this.addIngredients.bind(this)
    this.removeIngredients = this.removeIngredients.bind(this)
    this.calculateTotal = this.calculateTotal.bind(this)
  }

  addIngredients(product) {
    this.setState({
      ingredients: [...this.state.ingredients].concat([
        { ...product, displayId: Math.random() }
      ])
    })
  }

  removeIngredients(product) {
    const selectedProduct = this.state.ingredients.find((ingredient) => {
      return ingredient.name === product.name
    })

    const targetId = selectedProduct.displayId

    this.setState({
      ingredients: this.state.ingredients.filter((ingredient) => {
        return ingredient.displayId !== targetId
      })
    })
  }

  calculateTotal() {
    let total = 4
    this.state.ingredients.forEach((item) => {
      total += item.price
    })
    return total.toFixed(2)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Hamburger ingredients={this.state.ingredients} />
        <TotalPrice total={this.calculateTotal} />
        <ItemList
          items={ingrediends}
          addIngredients={this.addIngredients}
          removeIngredients={this.removeIngredients}
          selectedIngredients={this.state.ingredients}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App
```

Comment: Well we would like to see what are your tries, where are you facing a problem. We won’t do it for you, but we could help if you have some specific issues

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert React Context API Class to function of Hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64562934/convert-react-context-api-class-to-function-of-hook)

Comment: Try to do it in a code sandbox, and then you can share your code and we can help more!

Comment: When your question is answered please do not update it to say 'solved' and remove code.  This will result in anyone coming here for an answer at a later date feeling lost and not knowing what they are looking at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navarrro I hope this helps you! I couldn't test it but Is a good started for you, I use ES6 syntax...

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Hamburger, TotalPrice, ItemList } from './SuperComponents.jsx';

const App = () => {
    const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState([]);
    // You are not using this state
    // const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState(0);

    const addIngredients = (product) => {
        setIngredients([...ingredients, { ...product, displayId: Math.random() }]);
    };

    const removeIngredients = (product) => {
        const selectedProduct = ingredients.find(
            (ingredient) => ingredient.name === product.name
        );

        const { targetId } = selectedProduct;
        setIngredients(
            ingredients.filter((ingredient) => ingredient.displayId !== targetId)
        );
    };
    const calculateTotal = () => {
        let total = 4;
        ingredients.forEach((item) => (total += item.price));
        return total.toFixed(2);
    };
    return (
        <>
            <Hamburger ingredients={ingredients} />
            <TotalPrice total={() => calculateTotal()} />
            <ItemList
                items={ingredients}
                addIngredients={(i) => addIngredients(i)}
                removeIngredients={(i) => removeIngredients(i)}
                selectedIngredients={ingredients}
            />
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```